# How to make the "PageSetting" dialogbox of Notepad.exe in .NET app?

Tags: page-setup

I Want make a `PageSetting` dialogbox by .NET like this in Notepad.exe:

[image: PageSetting in notepad.exe]

I write the code use `System.Windows.Forms.PageSetupDialog`, it just look like this:

[image: PageSetupDialog in .Net app]

I tried the `PAGESETUPDLG.lpPageSetupTemplateName` with Win32 API, it works.
But the UI is too ugly.

How can I use only the .net class to make the dialogbox likes in Notepad.exe?

Comment: A lot of reading stuff is found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.pagesetupdialog?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The underlying winapi function (PageSetupDlg) has an option to modify this window with a dialog template, a capability that notepad uses.  On my win10 machine the template is dialog resource id #12 in notepad.exe.mui.  This capability is not exposed at all in the Winforms wrapper, you're stuck with default dialog.

Comment: Thanks to @Hans Passant.
I got an infomation from your answeer.
then I found the page is very helpful to the question.

[The link][1]


  [1]: https://www.zhihu.com/question/372723084/answer/1027877534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hans Passant.
I got an infomation from your answeer.
then I found the page is very helpful to the question.

[The link](https://www.zhihu.com/question/372723084/answer/1027877534)